# How to implement an ios app with facebook leaderboard?

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, leaderboard

I have a simple iOS app, which contain a score system.
I want to upload the score to Facebook leaderboard and compare with friends.
How can I do it?
I have no experience in this category. 
So please help me.

More detail:
I have completed a simple ios game, which would save the best score got by player.
I want to create a leaderboard of the score on facebook,like game center. 
so the score can be upload to the leaderboard shown on facebook.

Comment: What have you done till now to achieve that? Also, what is a Facebook leaderboard? Please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial/#opengraph for an introduction of the integration of iOS games and Facebook, and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores for the explanation how to use the OpenGraph Scores API.

There is also an Achievements API which yoou could use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements/

As far as I know, results can only be queried for the User who gave the Access Token, respectively the User's friends. So, an overall leaderboard cannot be generated via these mechanisms.

Additional helpful links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/bestpractice
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/opengraph/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/#scores